# Cannot create table in SQL Server (all created tables are in "External table")

Tags: sql-server

When I try to create a new table in Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio, all tables which I created are automatically saved to "External table".

When I tried to create a new database, I create table without that problem. I compare a "properties" between 2 databases but I can't find any difference.

[Screen after I chose a "table" option and created "produkty" table (saved on external)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AifjB.png)

Comment: what happens if you open a query window in SQL Server Managment Studio for that database and type `create table test (id int null)` ?

Comment: Actually it works. Thank you.